# How to temporally disable chrome extensions notifications

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, notifications

with new release of chrome 47, i'm not able anymore temporally disable notifications from bell icon in task bar in windows 7

when i play games in window-fullscreen mode, they appear and i prefer not to see them while playing games

in chrome help center, they suggest turn it off via "triangle button" in tray icon, then click "Customize", and set "Hide icon and notifications" for Goggle Chrome application, but this doesn't work, notifications still appear

thx

Comment: You used to be able to disable it in "chrome://flags", but it's not there anymore. Some sites suggested [disabling certain settings](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/babyOtRtMuw), but that didn't work for me, either.

Comment: the same issue on OS X